# Доступ к переменной вне блока кода

Tags: c#

Как обратиться к переменной value2 вне блока кода?

```
bytes = new byte[1024];
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    uint value1 = reader.ReadUInt32();
    uint value2 = reader.ReadUInt32();
    short value3 = reader.ReadInt16();
}
Console.WriteLine("Получили пакет {0}", value3);
```

Пробовал объявлять переменную до блока, и в блоке присваивать, но на выходе значение остается равным 0.

Comment: 0 это значение по умолчанию для типа Int. Запишите что-нибудь в поток или массив байт, чтобы получить что-нибудь отличное от нуля :)

Comment: @Sultanov Если я пробую вывести значение внутри блока, то выводил, а вне его выводит значение, заданное при объявлении переменной.

Comment: То есть Вы создаете массив `bytes = new byte[1024];`, он по умолчанию заполнен нулями и вы удивляетесь,  что с него считываются нули?

Comment: Спасибо, понял свою ошибку